# Анимация нескольких свойств css [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Допустим есть некий элемент, нужно заанимировать 2 свойства, но с разной скоростью и одновременно.

Анимирование конечно же методом `.animate()`

P.S Не пишите что-то вроде этого `$(this).animate().animate();` т.к происходит задержка как при callback функции в методе

P.S Нужно менять еще цвет, а с цветом происходят проблемы, он просто не анимируется если прописать свойство queue:false, либо анимируется ну уж очень странно (да я использую библиотеку jqueryui, без него нельзя делать анимации с цветом)

Comment: А использование опции `queue` здесь не поможет? Это если на JS. Может, в вашем случае и на CSS3 можно сделать эти анимации.

Comment: не там должен делать скрипт а не css

Comment: Тогда пробуйте через `queue: false` типа как здесь https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-simultaneous-animations-on-a-single-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `queue: false` для старта анимации вне очереди. Пример с http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( "#block" )
    .animate({
      width: "90%"
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 3000
    })
    .animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1500 )
    .animate({ borderRightWidth: "15px" }, 1500 );
});
```